# Double to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I try to do little program, to convert `DateTime` to `Double` and from double to `DateTime`.

I used `DateTimePicker` in C#, to make my users choose date and time to convert, and it works great, but I have little problem with converting double value to DateTime.

When I have double value, I can easilly convert it to Date by using something like this `var dt = DateTime.FromOADate(doubleDate);` and `var date = dt.Date;` but I have no idea, how to convert this double value to time.

This is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doubleDate = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    var dt = DateTime.FromOADate(doubleDate);
    var date = dt.Date;
    this.dateDateTime.Value = date;
}
```

Example value: `42722,7819696875` or `42710,5736342593`

Comment: `FromOADate` returns both date and time - `DateTime.FromOADate(doubleDate).TimeOfDay`

Comment: I tried this, but I want to assign the result to `DateTimePicker` form Windows Forms, and when I do this I have an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker'

Comment: Read the error.  `DateTimePicker` is a control, not a value.  Look at its properties.

Comment: `Value` is of type `DateTime`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the format on the DateTimePicker, Try the following:

```
var d = 42722.7465005671d; // 12/18/2016 5:54:57 PM
var dateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
this.dateDateTime.Value = date;
this.dateDateTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
```

Comment: The same answer like in comment up.

Comment: Changed answer, check it out!